# Каким образом можно реализовать добавление картинок в текст?

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения

Использую texBox.

Текст сохраняю в xml.

Каким образом можно реализовать добавление картинок в текст?

Comment: XML — это не формат, описывающий текст с картинками. XML — это метаформат, в котором можно описать что угодно. Придумайте формат на основе XML (то есть, решите, как вы будете кодировать куски текста, и как картинки), и сохраняйте в него. Да, `TextBox` не поддерживает картинки, вам понадобится `RichTextBox`.

Comment: как вариант переводите картинки в base64. Но тогда надо будет переводить их обратно в исходный формат. Прямого пути хранения картинок в XML - нет